# python, agent based modeling, loop

Tags: python, loops, modeling

In an agent based modeling, I'm generating a loop in which I have some steps as follows:

1. I want to solve a so-called 'problem' in which a variable named x has to be at least 10.
2. I have 3 problems that I'm picking randomly to solve.
3. Once I picked a problem, I have 5 iterations to solve it: i = 1, ..., 5.
4. In each iteration, the variable x is calculated.
5. If x is greater than, say, 10, then the problem is solved. (it could be on i=3 for example).
6. In any iteration that the problem is solved, I stop the iteration and pick another problem. Then I use the x I obtained from the previous step (step 5), (say, x_output) in the next problem's first iteration as an input (say, x_input = x_output).
7. However, if I was in the last iteration (i=5) yet the problem is not solved, I do an extra calculation on x, name it as x_output, and pick another problem randomly, and do the loop again.
8. I collect all the x_output's and let the loop run for any arbitrary numbers (200 times for example).

My question is how to perform this loop. I'd appreciate any insights. Thanks,

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Could you copy-paste whatever you have into your question with three ` on each side?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.